# Can't play DVD in linux

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

I run Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I know there are many questions about this, but none have fixed my problom. I follow correspondence courses, so I NEED to be able to play my dvd's. Some courses seem to work fine, while other courses work, but only on certain disks (The schoole help told us to use VLC, wow so helpfull lol). I can see all the files in the disk without problom (wich means that i can acces the files no problom?), but I am unnable to make the vob files play (curiously two of them do play), or load up the dvd in vlc. I have installed Libdvdread5 and all the othere packages I read about, set my region to 1 with regionset, and selected "no disc menues" in vlc. But whatever I do, I can't seem to get it to play. I know the dvd is fine because it playes on a cheap toshiba reader, and my mothers macbook. The vlc log is:

```
core debug: adding item `sr0' ( dvdsimple:///dev/sr0 )
core debug: Creating an input for 'sr0'
core debug: processing request item: sr0, node: Playlist, skip: 0
core debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
core debug: rebuild done - 2 items, index 1
core debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
core debug: resyncing on sr0
core debug: sr0 is at 1
core debug: creating new input thread
core debug: Creating an input for 'sr0'
core debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
core debug: requesting art for sr0
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
core debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
core debug: `dvdsimple:///dev/sr0' gives access `dvdsimple' demux `' path `/dev/sr0'
core debug: specified demux `any'
core debug: creating demux: access='dvdsimple' demux='any' location='/dev/sr0' file='/dev/sr0'
core debug: looking for access_demux module matching "dvdsimple": 20 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for sr0
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for sr0
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
dvdread warning: cannot open VMG info
core debug: no access_demux modules matched
core debug: creating access 'dvdsimple' location='/dev/sr0', path='/dev/sr0'
core debug: looking for access module matching "dvdsimple": 25 candidates
core debug: no access modules matched
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
core error: open of `dvdsimple:///dev/sr0' failed
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
core debug: finished input
core debug: dead input
core debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
core debug: nothing to play
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for sr0
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for sr0
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/sojan/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for sr0
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for sr0
```

Thanks for your help!

Sojan.

Comment: tried this already: `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

Comment: Your vlc log is worthless. First make sure libdvdcss2 is installed, ck with `apt-cache policy libdvdcss2` . If not installed then run `sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg` When that finishes run this to actually install it,  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`  If still an issue post back.

Comment: Yes it was installed, I re-ran the commands just to make sure, but it's all there, and the dvd still won't load.